# Non-empty field from Excel sheet shows up as blank in recordset

Tags: excel, adodb, recordset, vba

I am using excel vba to write a macro that reads data from an Excel sheet and processes it. Basically, I am copying data from an Excel workbook `A` to a worksheet `X` in Excel workbook `B`. Workbook `B` contains a macro that does this copying and then reads data into a recordset from worksheet `X`.

I'm running into a real weird issue. My problem is there is one field in the recordset that shows up as blank when I try to print the recordset value.

This is the part of my code that has a problem. `packageName` is passed into this function that contains a string. The recordset object `objRecordset` fetches the `Name` field incorrectly and shows up as blank when I try to print the recordset value for the item, even though it is non-empty. The other fields are printed out just fine. The name field contains letters and numbers like `ABC1232WHSJ, ABCD3456`. Any idea what is going wrong?

```
Dim objConnect As ADODB.Connection, objRecordset
Set objConnect = New ADODB.Connection

objConnect.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1

Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRecordset.Open "Select * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE Package LIKE '" & _
            packageName & "'", objConnect, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

Debug.Print objRecordset.Fields.Item("Package")
Debug.Print objRecordset.Fields.Item("Name")
```

Comment: Worked for me.  Hard to really test without your actual dataset though.

Comment: 1) See if the source column has any fancy format (like "Text") .... 2) could the "Name" field be missinterpreted as a cell address?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. Any idea if it has anything to do with "extended properties" in the connection string? Also, how do I ensure that the name is not misinterpreted as a cell address? The source has no fancy formatting. It is just a field containing csv's. I just manually created a worksheet with similar data and it worked fine so I'm thinking it may have something to do with the actual dataset but not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem.

Verify if columns has same number format.

When you use ado connection ado use a format for you first line . if is a number ,for example, and  second is string a value in table is empty (if create a table,else you receives a error)

The solution (work's for me) is open workbook before import data ,and format a column with a need format, i use propertie numberformat from range.

[]'s